# Difficulty understanding javascript toggle class

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change glyphicon-plus into glyphicon-minus on click event. here is my code

```
<?php foreach (get_categories() as $category){ ?>
            <div class = "sidebar_menu" >
                <li class="<?php echo $active = ($i==1)?"active":""; ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link(get_cat_ID( $category->name )); ?>" ><strong><?php echo $category->name;?> </strong></a></li>
                <div class = "floatright">
                    <li  id="cool">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne<?php echo $i; ?>">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the js.

```
$('#cool').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus');
});
```

It works for first list item only whereas I need to make it work for all list items.

Comment: Please, add HTML code instead of PHP.  It would be easier to understand. This is more jquery and not wordpress question.

Comment: @kuldeep-sharma Question needs bit more improvement. Do you want to change all list items on clicking any single list item or rather you want to change *glyphicon-plus* to *glyphicon-minus* & voice versa on just the clicked list item?

Answer (score 1):

some how i manage to solve this question:
here is my code

```
  <div class = "floatright">
            <li>
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <span><i class="cool glyphicon <?php echo $active = ($i==1)?"glyphicon-minus":"glyphicon-plus"; ?>"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </div>
```

and js

```
$('.cool').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-plus'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `#cool` selector and on click change class for "`this`" decedents. In this case `this` has only one decedent `"i"` element. Class of this element is changed.

Having HTML code would be more convenient in this case. We do not know what is $categories and other PHP variables here, so for this makes answering question more difficult.

Comment: i am very poor in java script. so what i have to do

Comment: First add HTML in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to replace the `ID` with `class` as `ID` is supposed to be unique. So your html would be like:

```
<div class = "sidebar_menu" >
    <li class="<?php echo $active = ($i==1)?"active":""; ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link(get_cat_ID( $category->name )); ?>" ><strong><?php echo $category->name;?> </strong></a></li>
    <div class="floatright">
        <li class="cool">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to change *glyphicon-plus* to *glyphicon-minus* & voice versa on every click then first checkout the existing glyphicon. Required function can then be performed on the basis of current glyphicon. So JavaScript would be like:

```
$('.cool').click(function(){
    var plus = $("#basic-addon1").find('.glyphicon-plus');
    var plusExistence = $(plus).length;
    if (plusExistence > 0){
        $(plus).removeClass('glyphicon-plus');
    }else{
        $("#basic-addon1").find('.glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-minus')
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks #mambro for your help but it does not work for me.